# How to get number values without double quotes in list using python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having lists as shown below.

```
l = ['22','abc','znijh09nmm','928.2','-98','2018-01-02']
```

I want those to insert in MySQL using Python, but I want it to get the output as:

```
l = [22,'abc','znijh09nmm',928.2,-98,2018-01-02]
```

Comment: The date value should probably stay a string? How does your python code to insert into your sql look like?

Comment: Your use of _insert_ and _output_ confuses me. Do you want to put the data into your mysql database? Do you want to print/output the data to console? What is the exact problem you are facing in your code (error message/stack trace)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to convert integers and floats in the list.

```
mylist = ['22','abc','znijh09nmm','928.2','-98','2018-01-02']

def convert(value):
    if str(value).isdigit():
        return int(value)
    else:
        try:
            float(value)
            return float(value) 
        except ValueError:
            return value

mylist = [convert(i) for i in mylist]
print(mylist)

[22, 'abc', 'znijh09nmm', 928.2, -98.0, '2018-01-02']
```

Comment: Thanks...But what about date?

Comment: @AishwaryaDhobale It's not possible to convert date string to int or float.

Comment: @AishwaryaDhobale If you want to perform certain operation on dates you could convert it to [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime) dtype.